# Git Sync local with remote

Tags: git, github

I have a local folder that is exactly the same as remote, with some files that i've included afer (test2.txt in the example). The problem is that I removed the .git folder from it. So I just want to add the git again.

Example:

**Local**

```
folder1/
folder1/test.txt
folder1/test2.txt
```

**Remote**

```
folder1/
folder1/test.txt
```

### What I've tried:

```
git init
git add ./
git commit -m "merge"
git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

I add the `--allow-unrelated-histories` because it was giving me the error `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`

At this point it's all a mess...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following :

- clone the remote in a new folder

  ```
  git clone [url of repo here] new
  ```
- in this new clone, `checkout` the correct target branch

  ```
  cd new
  git checkout some/branch
  ```
- now move the `.git/` folder from `new/` to your working directory

  ```
  mv new/.git  workdir
  ```

You should be in the state you expect.

Check that `git status`, `git diff`, `git add file2.txt` etc ... work as you intend.

You can remove the (now useless) `new/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without touching your working directory at all, although it requires some low-level manipulation with `git symbolic-ref` and `git read-tree`.

```sh
# Create an empty .git/ directory.
git init

# Fetch the remote repository.
git remote add origin <upstream-url>
git fetch

# Get Git's index to match origin/master without touching the working tree.
#
# We want Git's staging area, known as the index, to match the remote repository.
# We can't use `git checkout` as it would complain about files being in the way.
# We can't use `git reset --hard` as it would overwrite local changes.
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/remotes/origin/master
git read-tree HEAD

# Make this the master branch.
git checkout -t -b master
```

([Source](https://gist.github.com/noyesno/6f402a24ac02166fc0695227d8f7a386#file-git-checkout-index-sh))

Any files you've added, modified, or deleted will show up that way in `git status`. It will look like Git was there the whole time.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it by doing:

- Clone the repository in new folder

  ```
  cd /new/folder
  git clone [my repo]
  ```
- Copy the new folder to the old one (with the .git folder)

  ```
  cp -r /new/cloned/folder /my/old/folder
  ```
- Commit the new files

  ```
  git commit -m "add text2 file"
  ```

This way I committed my new files without losing them, and was able to "sync" my folder with my remote repository.